# Существует ли практика создания удалённых СКВ-репозиториев на хостингах?

Tags: хостинг, vps, контроль-версий, репозиторий

Стал задумываться об автоматизации обновления файлов на хостинге поле или внесения исправлений в файлы сайта/веб-приложения в локальной среде. Узнал, что есть плагин **gulp-deploy-ftp**. Как я понял, данная утилита будет прекрасно загружать новые файлы и обновлять уже существующие, но чего она не может - так это синхронизировать перемещение и удаление файлов. То есть полная автоматизация подразумевает, что если мы, например, удаляем какой-то файл в локальном проекте, то он должен быть удалён и на хостинге после запуска нужного таска.

Системы контроля версий способны отслеживать удаление и перемещение файлов. Но возможно ли создать удалённый репозиторий ни на GitHub, ни на Bitbucket, а на своём VPS? Я сам думаю, что да, но тогда почему эта практика не так широко распространена?

Comment: Потому что за VPS нужно платить. Плюс на GitHub и Bitbucket не нужно ничего настраивать - создал репозиторий, склонировал (или запушил) и работай.

Comment: Очень даже распространена, просто такие репозитории обычно не светят направо и налево

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, ничего запредельно сложного:

1. Ставите GIT на свой VPS.
2. На том же сервере создаёте юзера, настраиваете SSH.
3. Создаёте GIT репозиторий.
4. Подключаетесь и работаете с удалённого компьютера.

Вот несколько статей с более детальными инструкциями:

- Eng: [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps)
- Eng: [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server)
- Rus: [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

---

Конечно, это будет не так удобно, как какой-нибудь GitHub. И их код использовать не получится, ибо это не open source. Однако можно поставить себе GUI, есть варианты вроде QGit, GitK.

А если хочется полной автоматизации, чтобы все обновления автоматически заливались после каждого изменения, то можно после вышеописанных шагов написать скрипт, который будет регулярно проверять наличие изменений в проекте и обращаться к GIT'у в случае их обнаружения. К примеру, можно даже попробовать приписать этот скрипт к своей IDE, чтобы выполнять во время компиляции.

Comment: Немного странно, что умолчали про GItLab и Gogs