# Как коммитить разный набор файлов в зависимости от удалённого репозитория?

Tags: git, gulp, контроль-версий, репозиторий

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862582/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%92-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85) я узнал, что использование системы контроля версий действительно возможно не только для разработки, но и для деплоя приложения и работы с кодом продакшен-сборки. Напомню, что использование обычного деплоя через ftp (например, с помощью `gulp-deploy-ftp`) меня не устраиват потому, что трудно (а может и невозможно) синхронизировать удаление, перемещение и переименование файлов.

Следующая проблема, которая возникает - это коммит разного набора файлов в разные удалённые репозитории. Рассмотрим на примере проекта сайта. У нас будет как минимум три репозитория:

- **Локальный репозиторий**. В нём находятся ВСЕ файлы, кроме тех, которые были добавлены через CMS уже после деплоя сайта, а также сессий, логов и так далее.
- **Удалённый репозиторий для разработок**. В него не входят библиотеки **node_modules** и **composer**, некоторые файлы для локальный настроек (в случае с фреймворком Laravel это файл **.env**) и опять же всякие логи-сессии.
- **Удалённый репозиторий с продакшен-сборкой**. В него входят только те файлы, которые нужны для работы приложения. Будет отсутствовать папка для тестов, файлы для фронтент-разработки и так далее.

Если бы был только один удалённый репозиторий,то задача могла бы легко быть решена с помощью одного только файла `.gitignore`. Но в нашем случае набор игнорируемых файлов будет разным в зависимости от того, в какой репозиторий мы будем делать push!

Задача, конечно, решаема, если каждый раз в консоли указывать в явном виде набор файлов, которые хотим коммитить, и URL удалённого репозитория. Это будет километровая консольная комманда. Насколько это можно автоматизировать? Я сам широко использую gulp, но если одно gulp-а для этого не хватит, можно и написать что-то shell, если это кроссплатформенно.

Comment: *синхронизировать удаление, перемещение и переименование файлов* — [tag:rsync]

Answer (score 1):

Коммиты разного набора файлов для разных веток/репозиториев приводит к усложнению разработки и чрезмерному запутыванию.

Используйте один удаленный репозиторий и 2 ветки: master - для боевого стенда, develop - для стенда разработки. Все коммиты проводите по веткам по пути feature -> develop -> master. Создайте для каждого из стендов стендо-специфические параметры, например, whitelist с перечнем директорий/файлов, разрешенных к установке на данный стенд. Настройте CI/CD для установки обновлений на каждый из стендов с учетов стендо-специфичных параметров, срабатывающий по внесению изменений в соответствующую ветку.